# Navigation with an if that counts and add elements certain times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create a interactive nav bar for my own personal study purposes, so the idea behind it is if you click on down the number in the corner of the screen changes and a new image and text pops up every time this goes til number(page 5) all the other elements would be on display none except that one page that is active

I'd like to know if it would be possible to create a nav bar and lets say you have a set up nav with 2 buttons up and down how to make certain things not show up and others show up, i think my counter or var is not calculating properly, this is my javascript if statement( more in depth js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/emilegmn/1L3h51zw/ )

```
if(numberCount < 1 ) {
     add class to nav showing only one button ( down )
}
```

and this is my counter
    numberCount = numberCount + 1

and then after that between 2-4 to show 2 buttons ( up and down )

and at 5 to only show up.

If someone has any things or knows something online that does this, please link me to it if you want!

I have tried finding how to do this but I am still trying to get it all figured out,

Thanks in advance and for your time!

Comment: Could you explain some more? What is your code actually doing? (Is the code inside that "if" statement executing? What are the values of that variable as you click? Could you add the entire code where you update that variable?

Comment: added it to js fiddle on what i have now, it's not a lot tho https://jsfiddle.net/emilegmn/1L3h51zw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, is this what you want to achieve:

- User clicks between two buttons to make new things appear (like a slider maybe?) but in a nav bar.

To do so you need JavaScript as well as an HTML structure that helps you out. In summary, you could do something along these lines. Granted this only takes into account a sort of "next button", if you want a previous one then you just need to add another function that instead of adding to the `current_slide` , subtracts from it.

Happy coding!

**HTML**

```
<nav id="slider-nav">
    <div id="slide-1" class="active"></div>
    <div id="slide-2"></div>
    <div id="slide-3"></div>
    <div id="slide-4"></div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

With this you make sure that only the `<div>` with class `.active` is visible

```
#slider-nav div:not(.active) {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

This would be your sweet JavaScript (jQuery)

```
//To be placed within your document ready function
const nav_slides =[]; //Holds the id of all your slides
var current_slide = 0; 
$('#slider-nav div').each(function(){
    nav_slides.push('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
});

/*This would be the part of when clicking happens on the 'next' button in your nav. 
Keep in mind that the definition of the function must be within the same 
scope as the defined variable, current_slide and nav_slides. 
Hopefully, all encapsulated into one single scope that is your api.*/

function nextSlide(){
   $(nav_slides[current_slide]).removeClass('active'); 
   current_slide = (current_slide + 1) % nav_slides.length; 
    //Move on to next slide
   //It's a circular counter, when it reaches max slide 4, it'll go back to 0
   $(nav_slides[current_slide]).addClass('active');
}
```

ps: The initialization of `current_slide` is not dynamic. If in your HTML you happen to change who the first slide with `active` class is, then you need to update it in your JS. It would be very **useful** to initialize that `current_slide` dynamically, in other words, not hard coded out of laziness.

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to achieve! thanks for the help! once i hit my rep to be enough to give you a +1 i'll be back haha but for now this is marked as the answer for me! huge thanks!!, Edit: just checked the code, not fully what i need but i think i can start to make it work from here, i'll try my best! thanks again for the help!)

Comment: :) Glad I could help. A tip for the future, when asking questions tried to be more concise and precise, so that others can help you. It's hard to help when one can't understand what you are trying to do. Keep coding at  it, I'm sure you will get there. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do my best haha it's hard since i have the idea in my head but like i can't give it to you haha :) Thanks for all the help and thanks for the kind words and advice!!